# Pass directives through another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

We created some directives to speed up our coding and clean the htmls, for example:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="form-label">{{label}}
        <input ng-disabled="ngDisabled" ng-model="ngModel" type="text" class="form-control"/>
   </label>
   <div ng-if="invalidMessage" class="error">{{invalidMessage}}</div>
</div>
```

and the js

```
angular.module('ui.default-input', [])
       .directive('defaultInput', function(){
           return {
               restrict: 'E',
               templateUrl: '_component.html',
               scope: {
                   label: '@',
                   invalidMessage: '@',
                   ngModel: '=',
                   ngDisabled: '='
               }
           }
       });
```

So we can use it anywhere like

```
<default-input label="im a label" ng-model="vm.model"></default-input>
```

The problem is, whenever we want to add another directive to the input, we have to defined it in the directive own scope and manually apply it. (Like we did with ngDisabled and ngModel).

Is there a smarter solution? Is it wrong to use directives in that way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes there is, it's transclusion. I used it with inputs however i had some trouble with inputs because i lost the form for the validation so i ended up with a quite ugly part in my directive's code.

Comment: Makes sense, I'm going to try it out. Thanks.